# Does Chrome treat google map loading differently?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome

I'm testing this page - it's live but not really public yet.  http://info.iste.org/student-standards-contest

It is auto jumping to the start of the map (the header covers it a bit) in Chrome but not firefox or Safari. Does anyone know of a reason for this? My initial search attempts are not showing up anything promising. Does Chrome treat maps differently? Or are there any particular scripts that Chrome treats differently? I got the code to place the map direct from Google Fusion Tables if that is helpful.

Comment: Update - I now think it is actually the iframe that is using a fragment as the src or the input autofocus functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a difference in browser behavior, but it's not because of google maps. You can see this by taking these steps:

- Open a new tab in chrome
- Open the console (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>)
- Go to the network tab of your console
- Set connection to something very slow such as GPRS
- Load the page

You'll see that the page does it's jump before google maps is even loaded.  It's the other elements that are loaded onto the page shifting things around. Why Chrome does this and Firefox does not is probably some very minor difference in interpreting the page. There's a lot going on with that page so tough to say looking at it from the outside. Try removing elements that are loaded onto the page one by one and figure out which element is causing the jump.